# not able to deploy spring boot in weblogic

Tags: spring, spring-boot, weblogic

I am trying to run a spring boot application in weblogic server 12.1.3 but getting below error

> Blockquoteweblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(Ljava/util/List;)V
>       at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:140)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:216)
>       at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:211)
>       at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
>   Caused By: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.core.annotation.AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.sort(Ljava/util/List;)V
>       at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:167)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializer(WebAppServletContext.java:1394)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1331)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.initContainerInitializers(WebAppServletContext.java:1317)
>       at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1834)
>       Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

Comment: looks like you have somehow different version of spring dependency, can you post your pom/gradle file

Comment: weblogic ships with an older version of Spring. Add a deployment descriptor to tell for which packages to use the application version instead of the server provided version. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27005130/trying-to-deploy-spring-boot-to-weblogic-server

Answer (score 0):

you will need to add weblogic.xml under webapp/WEB-INF :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.3/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>onlinechannel</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>           
            <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>com.fasterxml.jackson.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```